# which pars push notification plugin is best for cordova android app?

Tags: cordova

I am developing an app with cordova for android. For push Notification which plugin i can use for pars. I am using **com.phonegap.plugins.ParsePushPlugin** it is working fine to me but **cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing** plugin is not working with this. any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

ASB

Uninstall both plugin using Command Line Interface (CMD) and then close CMD and again open CMD select your project and again install both plugin.

```
you can uninstall plugin Ex.  
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
```